# what should be the right approach for mass deleteing using JPA?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

one major doubt regarding  delete option in DAO layer!
which approach is better for mass delete when there is multiple where conditions are there,  and why ?:-

1 approach

EntityManager.remove();

2 approach

EntityManager.createNamedQuery(DeleteQuery);

thanks

Comment: and what about createQuery("DELETE FROM ...") ? i.e same as named, but not a stored query

Comment: or what about createNativeQuery(...) where you do a DELETE but don't want callbacks and cascade happening ?

Answer (score 3):

The NamedQuery, by far.

You can delete several rows with a single query -- that's a big win right there.

Even if you had to delete thing individually, with the EntityManager, you need to have the actual entity to delete. Whereas with a NamedQuery, you only need the key -- no reason to read the entity in the first place.

Much, much faster overall.

Comment: using NamedQuery is the better approach! right ! thanks